# ease-out after rollover disjointed image

Tags: css, fade, rollover

I have a disjointed rollover and I would like to add a timed ease-out (only) effect.
[I made a page with just that particular issue isolated, see here:](http://raphaelzwyer.com/testRapha/overviewtest.html)

When hovering over "overview" an over-view image shows up in a defined area and on roll-out the image disappears. All good but I now would like the image to fade-out after half a second, even if the pointer is still hovering over "overview" (not just only when the pointer is out). With other words, every time the visitor hovers over "overview" the image appears for half a second and then fades out.
I'm a newbie. CSS only would be great. I tried webkit ease-out/ease-in but couldn't really get it to show and then ease-out only.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>raphaelzwyer</title>
<link href="css/raphaelzwyer.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="raphaelzwyer stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphaelzwyerFive.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="header"> 
                    <ul id="overviewlayer">
                       <li>
                            <a href="portfolio.html">
                                <div id="overviewtext">overview</div>
                                <div class="overview"><img src="images/overview.png" width="660" height="1284" alt="overviewlayer"/></div>
                             </a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="wordmark"></li>
                    </ul>  <!-- end of overviewlayer -->
    </div>  <!-- end of header --> 

</body>
</html>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
#header {
        position: relative;
        top: 36px;
        left: 212px;
        width: 660px;
        height: 48px;}
#overviewlayer a .overview  {
        display:none;}
#overviewlayer a:hover .overview  {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 116px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 852px;
        width: 660px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 11px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        z-index: +20;}
.overview {
        position: relative;
        top: 12px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 852px;
        width: 660px;
        z-index: +10;}
#overviewtext {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 48px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        z-index: +600;}
a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #a9a9a9;}
a:hover, a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #be1f2d;}
li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use CSS3 animations for this ...

Add this line of code to `{ #overviewlayer a:hover .overview }`

```
-webkit-animation: fade 1.0s ease-out forwards;
```

and then add the keyframes to your css.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade

{
     0% {opacity: 1;}
    50% {opacity: 1;}
   100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

In this case, the image will show up immediately when you hover over 'overview' and then the image will fade out.

Since I've only added -webkit- for this example, don't forget to add the prefixes for Firefox, IE and Opera and keep in mind that this only works in modern browsers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, Christopher! Appreciate it!  
Works prefect. The only thing that doesn't work yet is the fade-out on roll-out. I wanted the roll-out to have the same (slightly delayed) fade-out effect. Right now it just immediately disappears.